# Load Image from URL into ImageView in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin.android

I am working on an app and want to bind the Image URL in image view of recycler i want to use picaso for this but every time when I add nuget package I'll got an error.

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'Square.OkHttp, Version=2.7.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying the error because it requires the add-on libraries OkHttp and OkIO. Add the package for Picasso and try again.